# Find the farthest sum of two elements from zero in an array

Tags: algorithm

Given an array, what is the most time- and space-efficient algorithm to find the sum of two elements farthest from zero in that array?

**Edit**
For example, [1, -1, 3, 6, -10] has the farthest sum equal to -11 which is equal to (-1)+(-10).

Comment: what do you exactly meant by farthest sum? ... provide some examples if possible.

Comment: Please be more exact in your question. A simple formula could help in disambiguation and show what exactly you are looking for, e.g. max_{i,j} | x_i + x_j |.

Comment: Reconsider rewriting your question. It is hard to understand.

Comment: I think you mean "largest absolute value".

Comment: Yea, there is the point. By the way is this a project euler question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a tournament comparison method to find the largest and second largest elements uses the fewest comparisons, in total `n+log(n)-2`. Do this twice, once to find the largest and second largest elements, say `Z` and `Y`, and again to find the smallest and second smallest elements, say `A` and `B`. Then the answer is either `Z+Y` or `-A-B`, so one more comparison solves the problem. Overall, this takes `2n+2log(n)-3` comparisons. This is still `O(n)`, but in practice is faster than scanning the entire list `4` times to find `A,B,Y,Z` (in total uses `4n-5` comparisons).

The tournament method is nicely explained with pictures and sample code in these two tutorials: [one](http://www.seeingwithc.org/topic3html.html) and [two](http://blogs.oracle.com/malkit/entry/finding_kth_minimum_partial_ordering)

Comment: Good idea. I think you can spare `n div 2` comparisons by re-using the first phase of the tournament. If I understand correctly, both of the tournaments start by pairing the elements and comparing the same pairs.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the sum whose absolute value is maximum, it is either the largest sum or the smallest sum. The largest sum is the sum of the two maximal elements. The smallest sum is the sum of the two minimal elements.

So you need to find the four values: Maximal, second maximal, minimal, second minimal. You can do it in a single pass in O(n) time and O(1) memory. I suspect that this question might be about minimizing the constant in O(n) - you can do it by taking elements in fives, sorting each five (it can be done in 7 comparisons) and comparing the two top elements with current-max elements (3 comparisons at worst) and the two bottom elements with current-min elements (ditto.) This gives 2.6 comparisons per element which is a small improvement over the 3 comparisons per element of the obvious algorithm.

Then just sum the two max elements, sum the two min elements and take whichever value has the larger abs().

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the array keeping track of the smallest and the largest elements encountered so far. This is time `O(n)`, space `O(1)` and obviously you can't do better than that.

```
int GetAnswer(int[] arr){
    int min = arr[0];
    int max = arr[0];
    int maxDistSum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; ++i)
    {
        int x = arr[i];
        if(Math.Abs(maxDistSum) < Math.Abs(max+x)) maxDistSum = max+x;
        if(Math.Abs(maxDistSum) < Math.Abs(min+x)) maxDistSum = min+x;

        if(x < min) min = x;
        if(x > max) max = x;
    }

    return maxDistSum;
}
```

The key observation is that the furthest distance is either the sum of the two smallest elements or the sum of the two largest.

Comment: but how to do the sum? It is not the difference!

Comment: What if your array is `-1,0,1`? Smallest is -1, largest is 1. Sum of smallest and largest is 0. Sum of 0 and 1 is 1, which is larger than 0.

Comment: @Petar: you compeletely misunderstood what I said in the question.

Comment: @glowcoder, yes, and that's exactly what the function will return (there was a non related bug, I just fixed, but the algo is the same). Try it :)

Comment: @Qiang, really?? So what are you actually saying then?

Comment: @Quang, ok so I return the distance. But it's very easy to return the sum instead. Look at my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the problem from a general perspective:

Find the largest sum of `k` integers in your array.

- Begin by tracking the FIRST k integers - keep them sorted as you go.
- Iterate over the array, testing each integer against the min value of the saved integers thus far.
- - If it is larger than the min value of the saved integers, replace it with the smallest value, and bubble it up to its proper sorted position.

When you've finished the array, you have your largest k integers.

Now you can easily apply this to `k=2`.

Comment: here, the farthest means absolute value. So it could also be the largest k integers.

Comment: @QiangLi My bad, I meant largest integers. :-) Whoops!